# AttributeError in Python Sage

Tags: python, attributeerror, sage

I'm really sorry to bother you with an AttributeError, but I just can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

My goal is to be able to access the C matrix's elements through certain functions I have not listed here. But for that to happen I figured I'd have to convert the matrix to a string.

```
from sage.all import *
import numpy as np
import random
import sage.all

def __NewTable__(C):
    A=np.array_str(C)
    word=""
    MS=[]
    for letter in A:
        if letter==')':
            word=''.join(letter)
            MS.append(word)
            word=""
        else:
            word=''.join(letter)
    return MS

length=int(raw_input("Give length of linear code"))
dimention=int(raw_input("Give the dimention"))
FF=int(raw_input("Give the finite field in which you want to work in"))
C = codes.ReedSolomonCode(length, dimention, GF(FF, "x"))
MS=__NewTable__(C)
print MS
```

I get the following error after giving the arguments (length, dimention, FF)

AttributeError: 'LinearCode_with_category' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: What is `GF`? It looks like it is not defined, and if it is, that is critical to figuring out what has gone wrong.

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to call `np.array_str` on a `ReedSolomonCode`?

Comment: @skywalker it's Galois Field, part of the definition of ReedSolomonCode

Comment: @user2357112 I'm just trying to convert the C array to a string so that I can manipulate it

Comment: You forgot to `import numpy as np` which Sage might like.  I also think it would be helpful to know WHICH input you gave for l,d,FF for testing.  Anyway, `ReedSolomonCode` still isn't an array that Numpy can manipulate.  `np.array_str(C.list())` also doesn't work.

Comment: @kcrisman Yeah, I forgot to include the imports in the question. What I'm trying to do is search the ReedSolomonCode for specific Values and their location in it. So I thought turning it to a string would work...

Comment: @kcrisman Also my testing inputs where l = 4, d= 3, FF= 5

Comment: Why don't you just use `C.list()` and make that a string in Python (as opposed to numpy)?  Or use a list comprehension on `C.list()` and make each element a string?  I'm missing something here in what your real goal is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AttributeError` exception is raised when evaluating `np.array_str(C)`.
Indeed, `np.array_str` is a function to convert a numpy array into a string, so `np.array_str(C)` starts by trying to figure out the shape of its argument `C` (expected to be a numpy array), but in your use case `C` is not a numpy array and has no `shape`.

One workaround would be to write

```
A = np.array_str(np.array(C.list()))
```

or you might get rid of numpy and just use

```
A = str(C.list())
```

and then you don't need to import numpy.

Tips to get better help:

- start your question by stating what you want to achieve
- provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
- in particular skip the interactive part (`raw_input`)

In summary, starting SageMath and defining `__NewTable__` as follows:

```
def __NewTable__(C):
    A = str(C.list())
    word = ""
    MS = []
    for letter in A:
        if letter == ')':
            word = ''.join(letter)
            MS.append(word)
            word = ""
        else:
            word = ''.join(letter)
    return MS
```

here is how that function would work:

```
sage: C = codes.ReedSolomonCode(4, 3, GF(5, "x"))
sage: MS = __NewTable__(C)
sage: print MS
[')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')', ')']
```

Not sure that's really what you want, but at least the `AttributeError` is gone and you can take it from here. Don't hesitate to let us know how this works out.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. This is actually a colleague's code that she left uncommented and I have close to zero python experience.. So yeah, your answer cleared some things up, but I still have a way to go. Have a good day!